# Hadoop DFS Permission Error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
2009/08/11 13:25:39 [INFO] -    put: org.apache.hadoop.fs.permission.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=yskhoo, access=WRITE, inode="":bad-boy:supergroup:rwxr-xr-x
```

Why do I keep getting this error when I try to put some files from my LFS to HDFS?

Answer (score 0):

The permission denied is what it is --- yskhoo was trying to access bad-boy's file.

Not sure about the blank inode name.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because, bad-boys in your case is Superuser. To be specific you're trying to put a file from your Local file system as a `yskhoo` user who does not have the permission to access HDFS directory that is why the error was generated.

Just like in Linux no other user can directly access `/root` directory except for the root user itself, the same way you can not put a file into HDFS if you don't have access to any directory inside HDFS.

I advice you to put the file in to /tmp directory and the try to put it in HDFS by logging in as a HDFS user(bad-boy in your case).